# Leaflet map not showing properly in bootstrap 3.6 modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, geojson

When I try to display the map in my modal I get this:

[image]

I have nothing in my controller angularJS and this is my html:

```
<leaflet lf-center="japan" geojson="geojson" geojson-nested="true" height="45vh"></leaflet>
```

Comment: You have to load your map after modal is opened. Show more code (modal and JS code that loads map).

Comment: I'm trying to implement this example : http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/geojson-nested-example this is my code js http://pastebin.com/3TN6S9LS and here my modal: http://pastebin.com/MvDdxcLP

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$scope.newMeeting = function(session) {
  $('#meetingModal').modal('show');
  map.invalidateSize(); // add this to your existing code
};
```

Comment: this is the first time I use this component, the map style displayed without any call (js side) so I don't know exactly where the map is called